# How can I kick member from voice channel? (DSharpplus)

Tags: c#, discord, dsharp+

How can I kick member from voice channel? 
In DSharpplus Api Documentation I've only found `Task PlaceMemberAsync(DiscordMember Member)` or `public Task PlaceInAsync(DiscordChannel channel)`
`await Member.PlaceInAsync(null)` doesn't work 
https://dsharpplus.emzi0767.com/api/index.html 
Thank's for your answer's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://dsharpplus.emzi0767.com/api/DSharpPlus.Entities.DiscordMember.html

There is a method "ModifyAsync(String, IEnumerable, Nullable, Nullable, DiscordChannel, String)"

Have you tried to null DiscordChannel parameter when modifying the target user? First check if its a voice channel, using https://dsharpplus.emzi0767.com/api/DSharpPlus.ChannelType.html.

Answer (score -1):

Now You need to use

```
 await Member.ModifyAsync(delegate (MemberEditModel Kick)
 {
     Kick.VoiceChannel = null;
 });
```